# If and last number to delete

Tags: bash, sh

Did I you something wrong?

I feel like I forgot something.

```
copy=${1}
y=".xlsx"
x=${#y}
if [[ ${copy}==${y} ]];then
     copy="${copy::${x}}"
fi
```

BASH keeps on answers yes to every.

```
#before
Copy=AAAAAbbbbb
Y= .xlsx
X= 5

#if the code: copy="${copy::-${x}}"

#After
Copy=AAAAA
Y= .xlsx
X= 5
```

Comment: what are you expecting as output? you're also missing a closing `fi`

Comment: "FI" Was in far-right

Comment: `[[ ${copy}==${y} ]]` is always true because you need blanks around `==`. https://www.shellcheck.net/ tells you things like that.

Comment: consider replacing the test with `[[ "${copy}" = "${y}" ]]`, making sure to place at least one space between `[[` and `"${copy}"` and `=` and `"${y}"` and `]]`

Comment: Thank you! It has been a while...

Comment: if you were to run the test within a `set -x/+x` wrapper you would see your test would be evaluated as `[[ -n AAAAAbbbbbb==.xlsx ]]` where the `-n` says to return `true` if the length of the string `'AAAAAbbbbb==.xlsx'` is > 0, hence the reason it always returned `true` and thus always chopped off the last 5 characters of `${copy}`